# Operate three-phase induction machine with slip higher than tipping slip

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering

Let's assume an 3-phase induction machine (IM) which is operated via 2-level voltage source converter which in term is supplied from a DC voltage source. Additionally, the IM is controlled using a field-oriented current control. The mechanical load is approximately linear and may especially have a relatively high inertia.

Neglecting the significance of this case, but what happens, if we operate the IM with a high d-current and a low q-current (to the contrary of the "normal" operating point).. at "low" rotational speed, the slip may be higher than the tipping slip. In my
imagination and neglecting the losses which occur in the machine, the IM will operate at this point without further issues.. i.e. after some time the setup will reach a steady-state with a certain angular velocity. However, the standard rule not to operate an IM behind the tipping point, makes me doubtful about this.

So the question is: Can anyone tell me whether there is some theoretical or practical aspect which needs to be considered in this case when the IM is operated with a slip which is greater than the tipping slip?

Comment: do you mean an induction motor?  Tipping point isn't used in induction motors since max torque is at speed of zero.  The problem with high inertia loads is becoming a generator.

Comment: tipping slip (the slip at which the maximum torque occurs).

Comment: Practical aspect is that you cannot ignore the losses.  An IM has high current (>100% rated current) at high slip (>5%), which will cause high heating in windings and activation of thermal protection or failure.